# Access other user's attributes (Cognito)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am building an application with a buyer and a seller (simplified).

Currently, I am facing the issue that I try to access the other user's attributes from the Cognito user pool.

**So the idea is:**  when the buyer would like to buy something (click on the buy button), I am storing a reference (e.g. cognitoID, IDToken, or something else?) to that user. With this reference, I would like to display the first name, last name, ... (user attributes) from the buyer in the seller's inbox.

The application stack is React(web) and AWS Amplify with a Dynamodb.

A very simple solution would be to store all attributes from the buyer when he/she is clicking the buy button but there must be a better solution.

PS. It seems pretty easy but I couldn't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you can store [IdToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token) of the buyer, it contains user attributes such as first name, last name, email etc. encoded in base64 URL format. You can decode the ID token to retrieve user attributes using a base 64 decoder or any standard JWT library. An example for verifying and decoding Cognito token can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decode-verify-cognito-json-token/)